# Как убрать стрелки слайдера slick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Не получается убрать стрелки слайдера на разрешении до 768px. Через breakpoint пробовал.. Не получается.. Если без breakpoint ввести  arrows : false, то стрелки исчезают. Но они нужны на разрешении больше 768px.. Помогите разобраться..

```js
$(function() {

 $('.single-item').slick({
  dots: true,
 })

 responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 575,
      settings: {
        arrows : false,
             }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Ну и опиши условие... Если разрешение такое сделай так, если такое то так....

Comment: Верстку только изучаю. И в частности с js работаю только первый день.  Далек сильно от него.. ВРоде делаю как пишут на форумах и на сайте slick, а все равно не получается..

Comment: Ну вот и ответ есть уже...

Comment: Но увы, простите  хамство, вы не учитесь, ты пытайтесь копировать...

Comment: Каждый учится по разному.. Если бы я изучал язык js, то проходил бы курсы какие то, читал бы литературу. Но он мне не нужен. Достаточно готовых решений. И при возникновении проблем, я ищу решения в интернете, если не нахожу, задаю вопрос тут. Разве не для этого создан этот сайт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно передаете параметры. В примере ниже стрелки будут на резрешении от 768 и выше

```js
$(function() {
    $('.single-item').slick({
        arrows : true,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                arrows : false
            }
        }, ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.. Помог ответ.